# MySql - Get field from table 2, If not then from table 1

Tags: mysql

I have two table `complain` and `repair`. I want to get `ass_to_per` [Latest one] from  `repair` or from `complain` if the `id` of `complain` is not present in `repair`.

**Explanation:**

I want to get the `ass_to_per` from the `complain` table, and also from the `repair` table. But there is a relation between them, in `repair` there is a field called `com_id` which is a foreign key. So i want to get the `ass_to_per` from `complain` and also check the `repair` for the foreign key, if any then check the `ass_to_per` of repair. If any then get it as result.

I have `sqlfiddle`, For online testing: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33433/6)

The table and data given below.

**Complain**

```
CREATE TABLE `complain` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ass_to_per` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `complain` (`id`, `ass_to_per`) VALUES
(1, 'frayne'),
(2, 'murad'),
(4, 'frayne'),
(5, 'murad'),
(6, 'frayne'),
(7, 'frayne');
```

**Repair**

```
CREATE TABLE `repair` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `com_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ass_to_per` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `repair` (`id`, `com_id`, `ass_to_per`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'frayne'),
(2, 1, 'murad'),
(3, 4, 'frayne'),
(4, 6, 'murad'),
(5, 2, 'murad'),
(6, 5, 'frayne');
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `complain` 
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT(`com_id`) FROM `repair` WHERE `ass_to_per` = 'frayne') OR `ass_to_per`='frayne'
```

**Query Result**

```
id |    ass_to_per
--------------
1  |    frayne
4  |    frayne
5  |    murad
6  |    frayne
7  |    frayne
```

**Analysis**

```
id | ass_to_per[complain] | ass_to_per[repair]
--------------
1  |    murad             |    frayne
2  |    murad             |    murad
4  |    frayne            |    frayne          //need this one
5  |    murad             |    frayne          //need this one
6  |    frayne            |    murad
7  |    frayne            |                    //need this one
```

**Expected result:**

```
id |    ass_to_per
--------------
4  |    frayne        //ass_to_per from repair
5  |    frayne        //ass_to_per from repair
7  |    frayne        //ass_to_per from complain
```

Comment: only 7 will be present in result right?? because 4 and 5 present in repair

Comment: My query is not perfect, what i want is in my expected result.

Comment: did you read my first two line?

Comment: can you explain?" if the id of complain is not present in repair." in that case complain.id=7 is the only element that is not present in repair.com_id right??

Comment: I update my question, a little explanation.

Comment: some more information will be useful. Please explain why you removed 3 row from analysis result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111389/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-fathah-rehman-p).

Comment: i think i need information i requested in last question only

Comment: Can you please explain why you added "frayne" in your query, and nothing about it mentioned in requirement explanation ?

Comment: yes, This is the `userid` who logged in to the system.

Comment: I am working with an existing database in my office and i got this. I know the database is not well designed, but they can't change it for me / my work. So i need to work with this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111406/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-strawberry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE()` will output the first non-null parameter it finds, so using a join you can probably get ass_to_per from complain or repair depending on which one exists:

```
SELECT 
    complain.id, 
    COALESCE(repair3.ass_to_per, complain.ass_to_per) as ass_to_per
FROM complain
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT max(id) as maxid, com_id FROM repair GROUP BY com_id) as repair2 
    ON complain.id = repair2.com_id
LEFT JOIN repair as repair3
    ON repair2.maxid = repair3.id
GROUP BY complain.id
```

If you want to further filter (like in your example on 'frayne') on computed ass_to_per, just embed this select as a **subquery**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    complain.id, 
    COALESCE(repair3.ass_to_per, complain.ass_to_per) as ass_to_per
  FROM complain
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(id) as maxid, com_id FROM repair GROUP BY com_id) AS repair2 
    ON complain.id = repair2.com_id
  LEFT JOIN repair as repair3
    ON repair2.maxid = repair3.id
  GROUP BY complain.id
) AS mydata 
WHERE mydata.ass_to_per = 'frayne'
ORDER BY mydata.id;
```

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33433/49

Comment: `complain.com_id` is not present. After removing it the result is like: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33433/18)

Comment: Did you check the fiddle??

Comment: I need exactly what i requested for.

Comment: let me check in my database.

Comment: I am facing some trouble, I have a lots of fields in my `complain` table. So how can i select all of them?

Comment: just add the fields you want after `COALESCE(...) AS ass_to_per`

Comment: Not good performance, But no other option... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id
  FROM complain c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM repair x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT com_id,MAX(id) id FROM repair GROUP BY com_id ) y
           ON y.com_id = x.com_id
          AND y.id = x.id
     ) r
    ON r.com_id = c.id
 WHERE COALESCE(r.ass_to_per,c.ass_to_per) = 'frayne';
```